# Firestore - does creating document reference count as 'read' or 'write'?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

from the [firestore doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web-version-9_7)

> In some cases, it can be useful to create a document reference with an auto-generated ID, then use the reference later. For this use case, you can call doc().

```
import { collection, doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 

// Add a new document with a generated id
const newCityRef = doc(collection(db, "cities"));

// later...
await setDoc(newCityRef, data);
```

> Behind the scenes, .add(...) and .doc().set(...) are completely equivalent, so you can use whichever is more convenient.

my question is that does `const newCityRef = doc(collection(db, "cities"));` count as 'read' or 'write' without using `setDoc(newCityRef, data)`?

Let's say if I generate 100 document references but don't save them at all, my 'read' or 'write' count is 0 or 100?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you are charged only when you read or save data from Firestore. The references are just created by Firebase SDK on client side.